# Spring Data Rest - can not update (PATCH) a list of child entities that have a reference to another entity

Tags: java, spring-data-rest

I have three entities: Parent, its Child and some Reference:

**Parent**

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "parents")
public class Parent extends LongId {

    @NonNull
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name = "Undefine";

    @NonNull
    @OneToMany(cascade = MERGE)
    private List<Child> children = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

**Child**

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "children")
public class Child extends LongId {

    @NonNull
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @NonNull
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Reference reference;
}
```

**Reference**

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "references")
public class Reference extends LongId {

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Length(min = 3)
    @NonNull
    private String description;
}
```

And their repositories:

```java
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface ParentRepo extends JpaRepository<Parent, Long> {
}

@RepositoryRestResource
public interface ChildRepo extends JpaRepository<Child, Long> {
}

@RepositoryRestResource
public interface ReferenceRepo extends JpaRepository<Reference, Long> {
}
```

Beforehand I persisted several Children with References. Then I created a new Parent with one child:

```
POST http://localhost:8080/api/parents
{
    "name" : "parent2",
    "children" : [
        "http://localhost:8080/api/children/3"
        ]
}
```

And have successfully got status 201 Created.
But when I try to add another child to **parent2** (update it with PATCH):

```
PATCH http://localhost:8080/api/parents/2
{
    "name" : "parent2",
    "children" : [
        "http://localhost:8080/api/children/3",
        "http://localhost:8080/api/children/4"
        ]
}
```

I've got an error:

```
{
  "cause": {
    "cause": null,
    "message": "Can not construct instance of restsdemo.domain.entity.Child: no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('http://localhost:8080/api/children/4')\n at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1]"
  },
  "message": "Could not read payload!; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of restsdemo.domain.entity.Child: no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('http://localhost:8080/api/children/4')\n at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1]"
}
```

If I remove link to Reference entity from Child:

```java
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "children")
public class Child extends LongId {

    @NonNull
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    // @NonNull
    // @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    // private Reference reference;
}
```

all works perfectly - **child4** was successfully adds to **parent2**.

Could you point me how to correctly update a list of child entities if they have reference to another entities?

Repo with this example is here: https://github.com/Cepr0/restdemo

Comment: try after adding another constructor in `Parent` class with this signature `public Parent(String name, List<Children> children)`

Comment: Thanks @abhishek! But this didn't help (

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia, I already have a constructor `public Parent(String name, Child... children)` and adding your one didn't help. (I have constructors in every classes - I use Lombock)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't believe it!!! 
I added an empty constructor with String argument to Child and everything worked!

```java
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "children")
public class Child extends LongId {

    @NonNull
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @NonNull
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Reference reference;

    public Child(String reference) {
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain why it worked?!

Comment: +1 same situation, the error message also displays **no String argument constructor/factory method**.It mentions me to add a string argument constructor, and I solved this problem.And I also don't know why it works.Have you found the explanation with it?

Comment: @g1eny0ung - no yet ))

Comment: I looks like this is a known issue, and it seems to be getting some attention. Here's a [Spring Data Rest Jira Ticket](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-1041?jql=project%20%3D%20DATAREST%20AND%20status%20%3D%20Open%20ORDER%20BY%20priority%20DESC) regarding the problem.

Answer (score 0):

None of these solutions will work. Sure you can create a fake dummy constructor that accepts a string so the error will go away, but that is useless seems it does nothing! (eg it will get passed in a string uri such as `localhost:8080/address/1` which is useless as no resolution happens to map it to a domain entity.

From my research there is no way to get this to work. As soon as you implement a custom controller you can no longer automatically convert a URI from the `@RequestBody` object to a repository managed domain entity. Basically spring data rest adds secret sauce to resolve URI's which cant be accessed in a manual controller you define.

There are probably methods you can implement to create a URI resolver but good luck with that as its more than likely undocumented.

As a workaround or 'hack'.. Try just use spring data rest repository end points, maybe even repository event hooks like `@HandleBeforeSave` or if that is not an option I have considered this.

This wont work as URI's wont get mapped to entities

```
   {
   "name": "joe",
   "addresses": ["localhost:8080/address/1",
                  "localhost:8080/address/8", 
                  "localhost:8080/address/23"]
    }
```

Instead create a DTO and pass in primary key which in the custom controller you do your own resolution (eg get address by Primary Key in the AddressRepository). This is quite a manual approach and obviously not ideal.

```
{
   "name": "joe",
   "addresses": [1, 8, 23]
}
```